# Python Bokeh: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, bokeh

I've been trying [this](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/embed/simple/simple.py) simple example of embedding in Bokeh - that is, embedding a simple bokeh-based graph onto a html file. When I navigate to localhost:5000, it throws up an `internal server error` webpage on my browser.

Normally, I wouldn't post anything here without some records of what I've tried, but there's nothing to try.  This is the simplest example of embedding, which I'm trying to learn, and it's not working.

Comment: Well, wherever you're running that `simple.py` is almost certainly giving you an error message (not in the browser). You should find that and update your question or it's pretty much impossible to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i just download that file, and add `debug=True` to the call to `app.run` then it shows an actual exception:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: embed.html
```

If you look in the directory on GitHub you can see there is also a `templates` directory with the `embed.html` in it. Did you copy the example file without also copying the accompanying (and necessary) `templates` directory?

Comment: Yup, that was the problem indeed. D'oh!